# What is the most efficient way to manage tracking waiters with futex-based locks?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, futex

I've been using a waiter-count approach to futex-based locks: adjacent to the futex `int`, having a second `int` that's a waiter count which waiters contending for the lock atomically increment before performing a futex wait operation, and atomically decrement upon return from the futex syscall. However, I've noticed that this has pathologically bad properties in terms of the number of useless wake syscalls performed when the number of threads running is greater than the number of cpus, which goes like this:

Thread A is suspended waiting on the futex, and thus has the waiter count incremented, but it's not going to receive a timeslice again soon because all cpus are in use. Meanwhile, thread B is rapidly performing operations that momentarily acquire and release the lock. Each time, it sees that there is a waiter, and therefore makes a futex wake syscall, despite the fact that thread A has already been sent a wake and just has not yet had a chance to run and decrement itself from the waiter count.

Is there any good way around this? I feel like there should be some safe way for the thread sending the wake event to do the equivalent of decrementing the waiter count (doing that directly doesn't seem possible since it would be hard to negotiate so that multiple-decrements don't happen). Adding one or more extra `int` fields to the lock state would be acceptable if necessary.

One alternate design I'm aware of is foregoing the waiters count and instead having only a contention flag on the atomic locking `int` itself. The way this goes, unlock operations clear the flag, and attempts (successful or not) to obtain the lock after it was found to be held set the flag. On unlock, if the flag is set, the wake operation is performed. I believe this design avoids the problem I'm experiencing, but it has a different issue: under low contention, a waiter that arrives while the lock was held will unconditionally make a futex wake syscall when it releases the lock, even if there are no other waiters. Perhaps this design could be hybridized with a waiter count to eliminate some or all spurious wake syscalls?

Comment: Is `futex` a typo?  `mutex` perhaps?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: No, it's `futex`. See [`man 7 futex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) and [`man 2 futex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html).

Comment: Silly question: Have you tried adding a `yield()` when the waiter count is high when the thread arrives at the lock? I.e. `if (__atomic_fetch_add(&waiter_count, 1) > SOME_CONSTANT) sched_yield();` in the hopes that the lock holder thread will get its time slice sooner? I remember reading some discussions about a "directed" `yield()` on LKML -- one that would allow the current thread to yield directly to lock holder/waking thread -- but I think the mess it would have made of scheduling priorities nixed it.. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Located it. It's the March 2014 threads *"Pre-emption control for userspace"* on the linux-kernel mailing list. The two threads can be read e.g. [here](http://marc.info/?t=139387059400008&r=1&w=4) and [here](http://marc.info/?t=139576882700008&r=1&w=4).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: The futex wait syscall blocks, so for a newly arriving waiter to explicitly yield would be at best useless, and likely counter-productive, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. On the other hand, there might be an argument for having the thread releasing the lock yield if there are waiters in hopes of giving one of them a chance to acquire the lock.

Comment: It does seem you want some kind of "wakeup pending" flag that gets cleared when a waiter actually gets its turn. What I am not clear about is if you are okay with the active thread stealing cycles to additional lock held operations while a wakeup is still pending.

Comment: @jxh: I don't mind so much if the "active" thread keeps taking the lock -- it's getting useful work done by doing so. What I don't like is that it's wasting 2000+ cycles per operation making a useless futex syscall.

Comment: If there was some way to flip your current active thread's context to give direct control to a waiting thread instead, would you prefer to do that, or would you rather continue to allow the current active thread to process work?

Comment: @jxh: I'm not sure. It might be a preferable behavior, but that's a really big hammer and I'd like to think it's a separate consideration from the topic at hand, which is just avoiding redundant wake syscalls for threads that are already unblocked (conceptually) but just waiting their turn in the scheduler to report that they've been unblocked.

Comment: I tried a simple `int locked_flag; int waiter_count; char wake_sent;` structure, clearing `wake_sent` and incrementing `waiter_count` before `FUTEX_WAIT`, clearing `wake_sent` and decrementing `waiter_count` after `FUTEX_WAIT`, in the contented lock path. In the unlock path, I test and set `wake_sent`; if it was clear and `waiter_count` nonzero, then `FUTEX_WAKE`. It performs really well, but occasionally deadlocks; races somewhere -- or my implementation is crap (I suspect it is). Probably the flag and counter need strict ordering to not race.. should do a timing diagram to verify.

Comment: I also tried a compound `waiters` with low bit indicating `FUTEX_WAKE` is already pending (count increment and decrement by 2), but manipulating it then requires atomic compare-exchanges, which tend to loop in the contended case (and a set of threads may get into a war until next reschedule); it was much slower in the contended case than simple counter and separate flag. I don't know if this helps you at all, but at least I tried :). Could you show your `_lock()` and `_unlock()` implementations?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible to have the thread sending the wake event perform the decrement, and still maintain an accurate waiter count. The key details are:

- FUTEX_WAIT returns an indication of whether it was woken by FUTEX_WAKE (zero) or something else (nonzero). A waiter woken by FUTEX_WAKE should not decrement the waiter count (it should assume the waker did so on its behalf); a waiter woken for any other reason should decrement the count (unless of course it is immediately going to wait again).
- FUTEX_WAKE returns the number of threads woken up: the waker should decrement the waiter count by this number.

The important point is that both sides know whether the responsibility of decrementing the waiter count has been successfully handed over.

Of course, the devil is always in the detail, and whether this scheme is strictly the most efficient way of managing waiters will depend on how well it integrates with the rest of the locking scheme in question - but it certainly deserves consideration.

Comment: The problem is that, in this scheme, you're subject to spurious wakes that cause the waiter to think it was woken intentionally when it was actually woken by another thread blindly sending a `FUTEX_WAKE` after making an atomic change to unlock an object, which was subsequently freed, and its memory reassigned to the new object that's now seeing the spurious wake. The only way I can see around this is to have a global contract that futexes never be used in a way that can give rise to this, but that's impossible to enforce if various application and library modules are all using futexes.

Comment: Also note that the only way to avoid the problem, even if you're careful to make an effort to avoid it, is to refrain from using atomics followed by `FUTEX_WAKE` when there are waiters, and instead use `FUTEX_WAKE_OP` to make the wake (effectively) atomic with respect to the atomic memory operation.

Comment: OK - it wasn't clear to me from the original question exactly how much control you have over the environment as a whole :) To my mind, unlocking a structure atomically and then calling `FUTEX_WAKE` on it is a bug, because by unlocking the structure you've given up the right to access it in any way (the memory may even be unmapped by the time you call `FUTEX_WAKE`); usually the solution is to separate the protection of access to the object itself (the object's lock) from protection of the object's existence (eg by using a reference count).

Comment: But if you need to work in an environment where such bugs exist, a simple scheme like this is certainly not ideal - though the failure mode (i.e. "always call `FUTEX_WAKE`") is at least not catastrophic if you're careful to handle integer overflow on the waiter count - but that begins to be more trouble than it's worth!

Comment: It's not that simple -- if you "separate the protection of access to the object itself (the object's lock) from protection of the object's existence" you just move the problem to a different object whose destruction also needs to be synchronized. And reference counting is not a solution to this problem; it's actually the canonical example where this problem arises -- a thread sees that it has the last reference and thereby destroys the object when it's done with it, but another thread which just released its reference might be about to send the futex wake for it.

Comment: Thankfully, `FUTEX_WAKE` does not semantically "access" the pointed-to object; rather, it accesses a queue of waiters, which is necessarily (assuming no race conditions in the userspace program) empty if the pointed-to object was already destroyed, associated with the current backing (if any) for the virtual address. Thus, there's nothing formally invalid about sending these spurious futex wakes, but if anything in the program sends them, it makes it hard to use the return value of `FUTEX_WAIT` and `FUTEX_WAKE` in any meaningful way.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to discuss this clearly over comments and in the absence of a specific example! Yes, you may be moving the problem to a different object, but (depending on the specific problem) that may be easier because the second object can have a different lifetime from the first (e.g. static & hence no locking).

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of how FUTEX_WAKE works... but doesn't the fact that the memory may be in use by someone else, or not even mapped, suggest that there's something wrong with doing it on memory you don't own? I guess part of the problem is that there aren't (as far as I'm aware) any written rules on how the futex calls are to be used by Linux processes - so it becomes a matter of convention what is acceptable within a given process.

Comment: In my view, the fact that FUTEX_WAKE on an arbitrary address is semantically permitted doesn't make it OK - just as it may be valid, in some sense, to call munmap() on memory you've just freed - but you shouldn't be surprised if this has bad effects on anyone else who's using it :) To me the fact that you otherwise make the return value of FUTEX_WAIT unusable is reason enough to impose a rule that you only FUTEX_WAKE memory you explicitly own!

Comment: In the refcount case: no, a thread that has decremented the refcount must not call FUTEX_WAKE on the object, because by decreasing the refcount it has given up any right to access the object. Instead it should unlock the object, FUTEX_WAKE if necessary, and *then* decrease the refcount atomically (freeing the object if the count drops to zero).

Comment: I agree it would be nice to have a convention that `FUTEX_WAKE` isn't sent on addresses not "owned" by the caller, but I think this renders most uses of `FUTEX_WAKE` invalid. Most of them could be salvaged via replacement with `FUTEX_WAKE_OP`, but some could not. Since historical practice has been to "misuse" `FUTEX_WAKE` this way (it's done all over glibc, for example) I think it would be hard to get a consensus from everyone using the interface to fix the offending usage.

Comment: By the way, I agree that your refcounting design with an atomic counter accessed after any potential unlock should work. The impossibility I was referring to was in regards to using a non-atomic counter protected by a mutex, which would be affected by the spurious-wake issue.

Comment: It's possible to make the refcount design work even with a non-atomic counter protected by a mutex: the key is that the mutex protecting the counter must be one that's *not stored in the object*. One design that works is having one, global, mutex that protects all reference counts - if objects (and references) are created/destroyed only infrequently this may be acceptable (and there are ways to improve efficiency if not). As to usage in glibc, I can't comment on that - it's been a looong time since I looked at the glibc locking internals. If this "bad" usage has become the norm, that's sad...

Comment: Yes, but obviously putting the mutex in the object (or in an associated object that's destroyed at the same time) is the only way that scales. As for glibc, what happened there is that Ulrich Drepper didn't even understand (or at least didn't accept) that pthread objects can be used to synchronize the end of their own lifetimes when he implemented them, and actually had them accessing the storage after the atomic release operation. Now Torvald Riegel and others are trying to fix them, but they've run into the question of whether spurious `FUTEX_WAKE` matters too...

Comment: "*only* way that scales" rather depends on the problem being solved and how exactly *it* scales :) e.g. as I mentioned it may be that objects are created/destroyed only rarely; you can improve on the single mutex by using multiple mutexes and hashing on the object's id (or address), etc. As to pthread objects being used to synchronise their own lifetimes - that's interesting, as I'm not convinced I've come across a case where that would be useful; do you have any references?

Comment: In programs that are avoiding global state, I think that kind of use is the norm, not the exception. The canonical example is reference counting in the form I mentioned (or any form without global state and atomics). In general, if an object is "part of" a larger data structure, you can use the container's lock to synchronize destruction, but otherwise you're out of luck. Another important usage case is synchronization objects for passing data to a thread start function; often you want these to live on the stack of the caller of `pthread_create`.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure I follow. If you've got an object that's protected by a mutex it contains, and there are waiters on the mutex when the object is about to be destroyed, that's clearly evidence of a serious bug: if one of the threads blocking in pthread_mutex_wait had instead been descheduled just as pthread_mutex_wait was about to be called, then the object might have got destroyed, and the mutex unmapped/replaced by another object's, before pthread_mutex_wait was entered. Or is there a different scenario you have in mind? (Might be appropriate to continue this discussion somewhere else?)

Comment: In the scenario where this happens, there are not waiters on the mutex at the time it is to be destroyed. The problem is that the unlocking thread cannot know this because it observed whether there were waiters at the time it unlocked the mutex; by the time it's sending the `FUTEX_WAKE`, the object does not exist and there is no way to read whether it has waiters or not. If you're wondering how such a waiter is observed but leaves without `FUTEX_WAKE`, it corresponds to the case where the thread which does the destruction marks that it's waiting but then gets `EAGAIN` from `FUTEX_WAIT`.